# После обновления fedora кулеры крутятся в полную силу

Tags: linux, kernel, fedora, asus

Достаточно новый ноутбук `ASUS RoG G501V`, стоит fedora 25 (основная ОС) и windows 10. На ядре 4.10 с куллерами было всё в порядке (начинали крутиться быстрее при нагреве), обновил ядро до 4.11 из-за проблем с nvidia. Проблемы с nvidia пропали. Но кулеры начинают вращаться с максимальной скоростью через некоторое время после запуска системы (10-30 сек после логина в систему). В windows изменений нет (следоватольно, можно предположить, что проблема не аппаратная). Пробовал колдовать с `lm_sensors`, но не получил результата и в процессе освоения инструмента наткнулся на достаточно низкоуровневые советы: попробовать взаимодействовать с драйвером напрямую (ну или что-то вроде того).

```
echo "100" > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1
```

Значение `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1` меняется, но
зачение в `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/fan1_input` становится равным -1 (до этого 25500). При этом скорость вращения не меняется никак (шумит совершенно без изменений).

```
cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1_enable
1
```

Вывод `sudo sensors` соответствующий:

```
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:       -1 RPM // до записи в pwm1 25500
temp1:        +31.0°C
```

На сколько не изменяет память ШИМ кулеров используется для уменьшения вращения, то есть, если нет никакого сигнала, но есть питание, то крутится во всю. Следовательно нет ШИМ управления, но питание в какой-то момент подаётся на кулер.

В bios не было обнаруженно настроек кулеров.

Собственно вопрос в том, как вернуть адекватное (зависимое от температуры, как раньше) ШИМ управление для кулера?

**UPD:** сразу после загрузки значение в `pwm1_enable` равно 2, но в директории отсутствует файл `fan1_target` (closed-loop fan speed control https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/g762)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, в настройках BIOS отсутствует пункт Hardware Monitor (или что-то подобное)?

Comment: да, правильно, есть:
дата/время, включение/выключение девайсов типа wifi, камеры и bluetooth (среди них нет охлаждения), загрузка и безопасность